# Should I skip the "d" in "pendant"?

Tags: prononciation

The word "pendant" means "under", e.g "I have study french under 6 years".

But when I hear my teacher pronunce it, he will skip the "d". So it will become "pen-an".

"Pendant une six semaine..."
"Pendant six ans..."

Is that correct ?
It's parisian french accent by the way.

Comment: The word means "during", not under. The d is most definitely there and is pronounced like the d in the word dent, tooth.

Comment: But my teacher don't say the "d". It's a CD book by the way.

Comment: @lambie i have changed the question

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Lambie is definitely right. Nor saying the D is just impossible. For a reason you will have to determine (probably linked to the sounds you are used to in your native language)  **you** don't/can't hear it. Listen to the word on [Shtooka](http://shtooka.net/listen/fra/pendant%20que). As you can see (mouse over) on Shtooka the man talking is from Paris.

Comment: [my teacher **doesn't** say]

Comment: is "I have study french under 6 years" even correct? Some idiomatic expression? It looks like broken English to me so that's even harder to compare both...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/d/ in *pendant* is articulated after and before the nasalized vowel /ɑ̃/, it's entirely possible in an allegro or allegrissimo speech tempo for the soft palate to stay lowered throughout and for /d/ to become thus nasalized as well, in which case, it would be realized as [n], so that we end up having [pɑ̃nɑ̃] instead of [pɑ̃dɑ̃].

It's probably one of those things that happen in connected speech when people speak fast, so I wouldn't say it's not correct but it might be considered as slurred speech by some.

Comment: Moreover, even if the teacher did pronounce /d/, the student would be likely to perceive /n/ because of the mental block so many learners seem to have when it comes to nasal vowels :)

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and I speak a parisian french. If I speak fast enough, "Pendant six semaines" can become "Pan ssmèn" with an emphasis on the "ss" part. I will never speak like that for a pedagogic purpose though

Answer (score 1):

I add this answer because the former ones seem to me a little confuse. The answer to your question is quite simple: Absolutely no French speaker will ever skip the "d" of "pendant". You will never hear "pen-an" from a French mouth as your heard it from your teacher.

I will add that your example "*pendant une six semaines*" is not correct French. You can just say "*pendant six semaines*" or "*pendant une période de six semaines*".

Comment: Sorry, but this is absolutely not true. Grandtout is perfectly correct in stating that the /d/ can easily get assimilated into the surrounding nasals in rapid speech, resulting in [pɑ̃nɑ̃]. What I think you mean is that no French speaker will pronounce _pendant_ as though it were spelt _penant_, which would be [pənɑ̃]. That is completely true, but that is not skipping the /d/ sound – it’s skipping a _letter_ from the written form and then pronouncing a completely different word; like skipping the r in <Paris> /pari/ and ending up with <pais> /pɛ/ instead of <Païs> /pa.i/.

Comment: I was not supposing [pənɑ̃] but  [pɑ̃nɑ̃], just skipping the "d". I never heard any one say  [pɑ̃nɑ̃] instead of [pɑ̃dɑ̃], even speaking quickly. I suppose you're not French, dear Janus?

Comment: I am not, no, but I have absolutely heard [pɑ̃nɑ̃] and many similar reductions/assimilations from many native speakers. Even just [pɑ̃.ɑ̃ ~ pɑ̃ː] is commonplace enough in my experience.

Comment: Have you seen the film "Snatch", starring Brad Pitt as Mickey O'Neil, a gipsy hardly no one can understand, because he skips so many phonemes that you have to be initiated to understand him? I'don't think we have to consider this is proper English...

Comment: I haven’t, no. I am talking here about perfectly average, regular native French speakers like Loïc above, having normal, everyday conversations. Naturally, you wouldn’t expect a newsreader to exhibit such reductions, but regular people? Absolutely.

Comment: I'm sorry still not to agree. Being a native French man, I'm sure no regular native French pronounces  [pɑ̃nɑ̃], but the case remains interesting, because it raises the question of your own ears, I mean the question of your own native language, that makes you hear French in a special manner. So what is your native language?

Comment: My native languages are Danish and English – but more than that, I’m a trained phonetician, and I have both transcribed and analysed recordings of natural speech in a variety of languages. 90% of what people actually pronounce when they speak is made up of sounds they would swear up and down that they have never in their lives produced – and that goes for speakers of _any_ language. Even people who consciously think about it are generally quite unaware of how big a role allophony truly plays in our speech.

Comment: I agree with what you say: My son's wife is Spanish, and quite educated too, and still, when I told her that the Spaniards could use the sound "v" because it's the wet form of "f", she didn't believe me. Also, English people probably ignore that they use 2 of the 3 French nasal vowels: "ɛ̃" as in the word "bang" [bɛ̃ŋ], and "ɑ̃" as in "granted" [grɑ̃ntid], [ɔ̃] being the only one they don't have in English. But I still disagree on [pɑ̃nɑ̃], though I agree with most of what you say.